# Magento advanced search 404 error

Tags: php, mysql, magento, search

Im trying to utilise a modified Magento Advanced search on the homepage of my magento site. I am using the helpful tutorial for the modified search here:

http://inchoo.net/magento/advanced-search-in-magento-and-how-to-use-it-in-your-own-way/

I have managed to load up the correct search into the homepage by using:

```
{{block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" template="inchoo/search/form.phtml"}}
```

However, when I search something magento returns a 404 with the following url:

http://powerflexshop.co.uk/cms/index/result/?sku=C0002

If I search, using the same base search file from this link:

http://powerflexshop.co.uk/skusearch/results/for/?sku=C0002

It works as intended. Has anyone any ideas why? I assume its because the search is appending the url using the page its loaded from, rather than where it needs to be.

Comment: note the /cms directory.  You might want to check /cms/index/result/index.php to see if it actually exists.  In other words, cms != skusearch

Comment: A sense of basic file/dir structure it does not exist.

Comment: @Wayners247 What it the url your are able to see in the form action? Try to debug with firefox?

Comment: The code is: 

<form action="<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">


That is inside the form file itself.

Comment: Interestingly, inside chrome its showing as:

<form action="http://powerflexshop.co.uk/cms/index/result/" method="get" id="form-validate">

Comment: Im not sure this is the correct/best way to do this. However, having set the Form Action to: /skusearch/results/for/

I get the desired advanced search result page.

Any thoughts on a better way to achieve this?